# Qml Row extend last element until the end

Tags: qt4, qml

I have a QML Row element with a Repeater inside it declared as follow:

```
Row {
    anchors.fill: parent

    Repeater {
        ...
    }

    Rectangle {
        height: 30
        color: "black"
    }
}
```

I would like to have the Rectangle element extends his width from the right side of the repeater to the end of the parent row. How can I do this?

**UPDATE**
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved using the code below because the Repeater width is not automatically set to be equal to the total width sum of all the items

```
Repeater {
    id: repeater
    ...
    onItemAdded: {
        repeater.width += item.width
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
Row {
    anchors.fill: parent

    Repeater {
        id: repeater
        ...
    }

    Rectangle {
        height: 30
        color: "black"
        width: parent.width - repeater.width
    }
}
```

Comment: it works so so. It extends to the right the rectangle but it doesn't respect the parent Row width and so it goes out of the parent border and continue to the end of the window.

Comment: It it has, you should substract the left margin of the row from the width of the black rectangle: `parent.width - repeater.width - parent.anchors.leftMargin`.

Comment: no it hasn't margins set, the margins are applied to a parent item. I tried removing parent.anchors.leftMargin without success. To start seeing a reduced size of the rectangle I had to manually subtract a big number like 300

Comment: I think you should substract all the margins that are on the left side of the row, even the left margin of the row's parent's parent, or of the row's parent's parent's parent... or, if you are using `x` to make that whitespace on the left of the row, you should substract the value of that `x`. I hope that Qt developers will look into making some attached properties such as `Row.extend`.

Comment: I solved the problem using the onItemAdded event to calculate the width of the repeater. Otherwise, the width is 0. I really hope too that in the future there will be something like Row.extend